# Put jquery mobile autocomplete and select side by side

Tags: jquery-mobile

I am trying to put a jquerymobile mobile (using version 1.3) selectmenu and autocomplete side by side, but the autocomplete search-box is not aligned with the selectmenu and is cut-off at the top.

I've tried this

```
<div class="ui-grid-a">
 <div class="ui-block-a" style="float:left;">
   <label for="TargetTypeList" class="ui-hidden-accessible">All Uses</label>
   <select name="TargetTypeList" id="TargetTypeList">
    <option value="standard">Standard: 7 day</option>
    <option value="rush">Rush: 3 days</option>
  </select>
</div>
<div class="ui-block-b" style="float:left;">
  <ul data-role="listview" data-inset="true" data-filter="true" data-filter-reveal="true" data-filter-placeholder="Search cars...">
<li><a href="#">Acura</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Audi</a></li>
<li><a href="#">BMW</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Cadillac</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Chrysler</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Dodge</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Ferrari</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Ford</a></li>
<li><a href="#">GMC</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Honda</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Hyundai</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Infiniti</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Jeep</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Kia</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Lexus</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Mini</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Nissan</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Porsche</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Subaru</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Toyota</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Volkswagen</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Volvo</a></li>
</ul>
    </div>
```

(live demo at: http://jsfiddle.net/gE44j/) and table layouts with no luck.

Any ideas how to format them properly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

jQM adds negative margins around the filter input. Try adding this CSS:

```
.ui-listview-filter-inset {
    margin: 4px 0 0 0 !important;
}
```

> **[UPDATED FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/ezanker/gE44j/1/)**

Comment: Thanks! I figured that and was doing it by adding .ui-listview-filter {

    margin: 0 0 0 !important;;
} but that added a thick shadow around it. Your solution works perfectly!